# Postgres - How to generate dynamic daterange

Tags: postgresql

I have a daterange column in table, and I want to get all rows where the daterange overlaps with a given daterange which is to be generated dynamically - lets say [somedynamicdate-30days, somedynamicdate).

How to create this daterange dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an appropriate [constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT), e.g.:

```
with my_data(d) as (
    values ('2017-12-01'::date)
)

select daterange(date(d- interval '30days'), d)
from my_data;

        daterange        
-------------------------
 [2017-11-01,2017-12-01)
(1 row)
```